# $.get not returning html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

My Simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$.get("http://www.facebook.com",function(data){
alert(data);});

});</script></head>

 <body>
</body>
</html>
```

It should alert the facebook content but it is not doing so

UPDATE

Now iam using php

```
<?php
 $str=file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com");
    echo strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($str)); 
?>
```

Why it is not removing tags?

Comment: This is cross-domain request and it won't work. Only something like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) requests will work.

Comment: because you encoded them with `htmlspecialchars()` and therefore are not tags anymore but HTML entities.

Comment: But when remove htmlsecialchars and just use strip_tag then it is showing me a lot of js code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If youre using php on the serverside. You could create a service that returns the html using:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.facebook.com');
```

ASP.NET:

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
    string html = client.DownloadString("http://www.facebook.com'");
}
```

Comment: Your solution work perfectly but i only want the text which is shown by facebook to everyone not the html code and js code

Comment: @Webtecher Get the parts of the content that you want using eitehr jquery selectors on the data (if fetched by an ajax call) or use regular expressions. Why not just use an iframe for this? :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess you have just been blocked by the browser due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). See the console, and you will have a warning if you try to do this.

Without [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or a server-side proxy, you cannot read cross-domain pages.

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to have a server-script *on your domain* read the foreign page (wget, curl, fopen, what else is there) and return it to your page. Your server acts like a "bridge" to read the remote page.

You might have heard of [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) which does not have cross-domain restrictions, but what you are retrieving this way is not HTML/pages but scripts.

Comment: Then please tell me the correct method,if possible

Comment: @Webtecher — That's the second paragraph of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot request content from external websites due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) unless using JSONP. However, because you are requesting HTML this is not applicable.

The alternative is to make a server-side proxy to get the HTML of the facebook.com homepage, and then provide that local URL to the `$.get()` function.

Comment: Then please tell me the correct method,if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax requests in same domain only

however you can use JSONP to make cross-domain requests
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Refer to this article on ibm developerworks:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/

Comment: the OP is requesting pages, not scripts containing data.

Comment: even we can get web-pages with this method, refer to the article @JosephtheDreamer

Comment: yes you can, but you need to wrap it in a callback. The OP is directly requesting an HTML page. How would you do that in JSONP? can you provide a procedure?

Comment: yea I agree, directly requesting the url is not possible, however OP can implement the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on the other domain http://mzl.la/JOvUK6. In asp.net OP can use `WebClient` class from `System.Net` namespace, In php OP can use `curl` to get remote site data. http://bit.ly/KwluwS  http://bit.ly/Jr9IFx